# How to disable event receiver in feature deactivated?

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

I am new SharePoint programming.

I have created event receiver on item adding for the document library that allows only `.doc` files to be uploaded, otherwise it gives error.

My code for event receiver is:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
    if (!properties.AfterUrl.EndsWith("doc"))
    {
       properties.Cancel = true;
       properties.ErrorMessage = "Only .doc files are accepted";
    }
}
```

Now I want to make it active only the time the feature is active, when the feature is deactivated the event receiver should also be disabled. I think it may be possible with FeatureDeactivating() method.

How to implement it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in the Feature Deactivated event (if feature is site scoped, otherwise you would need to open the web and site a bit different as you see):

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite((properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite).ID))
 {
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
   SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
   SPList list = web.Lists["My List"];

   SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection erdc = list.EventReceivers;
   List <SPEventReceiverDefinition> eventsToDelete = new List <SPEventReceiverDefinition>();

   foreach (SPEventReceiverDefinition erd in erdc)
   {
    if (erd != null)
    {
     try
     {
      eventsToDelete.Add(erd);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
      Console.Write(e.ToString());
     }
    }
   }
   foreach (SPEventReceiverDefinition er in eventsToDelete)
   {
    //if(er.Type == SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded)
    er.Delete();
   }  
  }
 }
```

from here : http://sarangasl.blogspot.se/2009/11/remove-event-receiver-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: The code runs without error but `SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection erdc = list.EventReceivers;` fetches nothing.. @Robert Lindgren

Comment: Strange, you are on the correct list on the correct web?

Comment: Yes sir, I debugged the program and `list` object is also being created so it proves that list is correct..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SPContentType ct = web.ContentTypes[CtName];
if (ct != null && ct.EventReceivers != null && ct.EventReceivers.Count == 0)
{
    SPEventReceiverDefinition ev =
    ct.EventReceivers.Cast<SPEventReceiverDefinition>()
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == EventReceiverAddedName);
    if (ev == null)
        return;
    ev.Delete();
    ev.Update();
    ct.Update(true);
}
```

Really simplet to use. You will just need name of content type (where the event receiver is activated) and name of the assigned event receiver.